# iAd Banner causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access, instruments, iad

*Once upon a time there was an iAd Banner who worked perfectly. One day it decided to cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS whenever it was tapped for no apparent reason.*

So I'm working on a little iOS game that has an iAd Banner at the top of the screen. When `bannerViewActionShouldBegin: willLeaveApplication:` is called I send an NSNotification to pause the game, then I return `TRUE`.
It used to work as expected, until 2 days ago when tapping the banner started causing `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

The relevant code relating to the banner is thus:

**Header:**

```
@interface JAGameBackground : UIView <ADBannerViewDelegate>
{
    ...
    ADBannerView *adBannerView;
}
```

**Main:**

```
+(id)gameView
{
    JAGameBackground *aBackground = [[JAGameBackground alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height + [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width)];

    aBackground.adBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    aBackground.adBannerView.delegate = aBackground;
    [aBackground addSubview:aBackground.adBannerView];
...
   return aBackground;
}

-(BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_PAUSE object:nil];
    return TRUE;
}
```

And running it with Instruments:
[image: NSZombie in Instruments]

Any ideas on how to give this issue a fairy-tale ending?

Comment: The first line in gameView looks suspicious. It looks like your'e calling the initializer for JAGameBackground a second time.

Comment: A second time? My understanding of it is that it returns an initialized instance

Comment: you should create a class method and create the instance with [[JAGameBackground alloc] initWithFrame: ...]

Comment: OK, I have updated my code. The `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` remains at large

Comment: Do you use ARC for your project? Did you know the code line where this error occurred?(You can catch all exception to do it)

Comment: Thanks @NtVietHung - catching all exceptions was what helped me to realise it wasn't on the main thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had made the mistake of not loading the iAd Banner (along with other UIKit objects) on the main thread...